# Deleting anonymous wp_users function not working?

Tags: users

So I am "blessed" with anonymous users' data created by the plugin WP e-commerce in `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` (this particular WP setup is highly customized).

I am trying the following must use plugin, but I don't think the function is triggered at all:

```
// Remove users and meta data.
function fix_wpsc_clear_customer_meta_andre() {
//test
    echo "TEST wpsc clear function";
        wp_mail('xxxx@gmail.com','WPSC delete users','function been called/triggered?');
    exit();
//end test
    global $wpdb;
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
    $purge_count = 200;
    $sql = "
        SELECT user_id
        FROM {$wpdb->usermeta}
        WHERE
        meta_key = '_wpsc_last_active'
        AND meta_value < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - " . WPSC_CUSTOMER_DATA_EXPIRATION . "
        LIMIT {$purge_count}
    ";
    // Do this in batches of 200 to avoid memory issues when there are too many
    // anonymous users.
    @set_time_limit( 0 ); // no time limit
    do {
        $ids = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
        $included_ids = array();
        foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
            $included_ids[$id] = $id;
        }
        $in = implode(',', $included_ids);
        $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $wpdb->users WHERE ID IN ($in)" );
        $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE user_id IN ($in)");
    } while ( count( $ids ) == $purge_count );
    // Update number of users.
        $tmp_total_users = count_users();
        /*echo 'test: '.$tmp_total_users;
        exit();*/
    update_option('user_count', $tmp_total_users['total_users'] );
}
function fix_reset_wpsc_cron_andre() {
    remove_action( 'wpsc_hourly_cron_task', '_wpsc_clear_customer_meta' );
    add_action( 'wpsc_hourly_cron_task', 'fix_wpsc_clear_customer_meta_andre' );
}
```

i add this test code bit

```
function fix_wpsc_clear_customer_meta_andre() {
    echo "TEST wpsc clear function";
wp_mail('xxxx@gmail.com','WPSC delete users','function been called');
    exit();
}
```

In `wp-config.php`,  I have set `WPSC_CUSTOMER_DATA_EXPIRATION` to 1 minute

```
define( 'WPSC_CUSTOMER_DATA_EXPIRATION', 60 );
```

But I don't receive an email. So, how can I check if `add_action( 'wpsc_hourly_cron_task', 'fix_wpsc_clear_customer_meta_andre' );` is valid?

Comment: Do you dev your site on local or online ?
What is the event that triggered your function ?

Comment: @Nozifel, at 1st I develop local and when i put it live the function seem to work, when i call it directly in functions.php. But i liked to use `add_action( 'wpsc_init', 'fix_wpsc_clear_customer_meta' );` Now i am thinking maybe wpsc_init is not working correctly. How can i check this? And in general is functions.php loaded before or after the wp-ecommerce plugin??